# Did variable take more storage than intering direct number

Tags: python, variables, storage

```
def add(a,b):
   print(a+b)
#method 1
add(2,3)
#method 2
a = 2
b = 3
add(a,b)
```

#in these two methods which method take less storage please tell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you define "storage"? But in any case, the `add(2,3)` uses less lines of code and variables (so less memory in the longer term)

Comment: Supposing a compiler, that may not be the case. I think in other languages, a C compiler might decide to inline a function at will, derive that the outcome of this code is always 5 and replace the whole code with just 5, though that depends on the optimization level... (supposing a and b' lifecycle end after add)

Comment: Worth noting that in this particular example you will save ~56 bytes. Also, Python does not release the memory right after it doesn't need to be allocated anymore, so chances are you will have this 56 allocated for Python process already.

Answer (score 0):

When using the second method, you declare two variables `a` and `b` before the function call that takes space in memory. Meanwhile, in the first one, you are just invoking the `add()` function without creating any more variables or occupying memory space, that's because you are directly assigning the values of the function arguments without external data storage.